# Java - Swapping multiple JFrames on button press

Tags: java, swing, button, jframe, jpanel

this is the first time I've had a look at JFrames and JPannels and I've come a little stuck.

What I am trying to do is this, I wish to have an starting screen then based on the users button choice it swaps to another screen. To start I have only 2 screens, however once I've moved on there will be multiple screens. I've looked at CardLayout and while that is good it's not the way I wish to go I want to be able to do this first. Here is what I have.

Main.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
public class Main extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
protected boolean someCondition = false;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Main frame = new Main();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Main() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    if( someCondition == false ){
        showTest();
        someCondition = test.needToReg();
    }else{
        showTest2();
    }
}

private void showTest(){
    contentPane.removeAll();
    contentPane.add(new test());
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}

private void showTest2(){
    contentPane.removeAll();
    contentPane.add(new test2());
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}
```

}

test.java

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class test extends JPanel {
    private JTextField textField;
    protected static boolean toReg = false;

    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */
    public test() {
        setLayout(null);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Mouse Clicked");
                System.out.println("Before " + toReg);
                toReg = true;
                System.out.println("After " + toReg);
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(188, 166, 89, 23);
        add(btnNewButton);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(150, 135, 86, 20);
        add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JRadioButton rdbtnNewRadioButton = new JRadioButton("New radio button");
        rdbtnNewRadioButton.setBounds(6, 166, 109, 23);
        add(rdbtnNewRadioButton);
    }

    public static boolean needToReg(){
        return toReg;
    }
}
```

test2.java

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class test2 extends JPanel {

    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */
    public test2() {
        setLayout(null);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton.setBounds(56, 59, 89, 23);
        add(btnNewButton);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(122, 165, 46, 14);
        add(lblNewLabel);

    }
}
```

Running the program with the outputs I included I get this.

```
Mouse Clicked
Before false
After true
Mouse Clicked
Before true
After true
Mouse Clicked
Before true
After true
Mouse Clicked
Before true
After true
Mouse Clicked
Before true
After true
```

I hope it's clear what I am trying to do and I hope you can lend a hand with this. Thanks

Comment: *"I've looked at CardLayout and while that is good it's not the way I wish to go I want to be able to do this first."*  Good luck with that, I think it is silly to not use the best way.  I'm voting to close as 'too localized'.

Comment: What's wrong with using Cardlayout? its purpose is to allow the user to switch between layouts like a stack cards. How you are switching right now is not a good way of implementing it. Take a look at the tutorial again. It does exactly what you want http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

Comment: @AndrewThompson Whats wrong with wishing to expand your knowledge by looking at other ways of doing things? Seems silly to me to limit your knowledge simply as the way you are learning is not the best way. The way, I feel, to improve is try things out, see what happens. Just doing the best way won't make you better. Just my opinion.

Comment: @Aboutblank I will have another look like suggested, my only original issue was it seemed limiting. However, if that is not the case then I will attempt implementing it like that, thanks. On the original question if you have an idea about it just so I can have an idea how it works even if it's not a good idea it would be welcomed.

Comment: "Come one, come all, & leave your wrecking ball at home! We'll teach you to how demolish a wall with only the power of your head.  BYO crash helmet."

Comment: @AndrewThompson Attempting to prove a point by using completely idiotic examples is not a good way to prove your way is best, to me that just shows immaturity. However, playing on your scenario. While that might not be the best, the simplest, the safest way to do it. Are you denying it's a way to do it. If it works, it works. Yes it might be silly. However if those people used that method, found how hard and silly it was do you not think they would appreciate and find the wrecking ball that much easier in the future when they used that? Something to ponder

Comment: There's nothing wrong with expanding your knowledge by re-implementing an existing solution. The problem is, you need to have a good understanding of the existing solution and the context around it to actually approach this. You say "this is the first time I've had a look at JFrames and JPannels" - this is like "I've taken a few piano lesson and now I want to transcribe 'Gangnam Style' from a recording."

Comment: While you are learning how to use a CardLayout. Learn how to use Layout Managers as well. Swing was designed to be used with Layout Managers. You should not be using a null layout and setBounds().

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

On clicking the **screenSwapper** button in the main frame a new Panel is added to the main frame that can have multiple components I have added one button only

On second click this panel is removed and second panel is added to the main frame and previous one is removed.

The swapping is carried as you click the button continuously

You may use two singletons if you want to preserve once created panel in case of **MyPanel1** and MyPanel2

You may add more components on each panel and test.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public boolean switcher;
    public JPanel currentPanel;
    public JPanel panel1;
    public JPanel panel2;

    public Test() {

        this.switcher = false;
        this.currentPanel = null;
        this.setSize(200, 200);

        panel1 = new JPanel();

        JButton screenSwapper = new JButton("Screen Swapper");

        panel1.add(screenSwapper);

        panel2 = new JPanel();

        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        this.getContentPane().add(panel1);
        this.getContentPane().add(panel2);

        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        screenSwapper.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                if (switcher == false) {
                    currentPanel = new MyPanel1();
                    switcher = true;

                    if (panel2.getComponentCount() != 0) {
                        panel2.removeAll();
                    }

                } else {

                    switcher = false;
                    currentPanel = new MyPanel2();

                    if (panel2.getComponentCount() != 0) {
                        panel2.removeAll();
                    }

                }

                panel2.add(currentPanel);
                panel2.repaint();
                panel2.revalidate();
            }

        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
    }

}
```

This is the first panel

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;

import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class MyPanel1 extends  JPanel{



     public MyPanel1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        this.add(new Button("Button1"));

    }




}
```

This is the second Panel

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class MyPanel2 extends JPanel {



    public MyPanel2() {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        this.add(new JButton("button2"));
    }
}
```

Comment: This may work, but revalidate() should be done before repaint(). Also, what about the requirement for multiple panels? Anytime you see code using if/else statements or hardcoded panel names you know the code will not be easy to modify as the number of panels grows. The CardLayout already has an API to manage this. There is no need to try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @camickr yes I agree totally with you Little mistake on revalidate sorry for that but user is not comfortable with card layoyut so this is a alternate solution I could make quickly

Comment: @camickr I have not used any design patterns here that way we can surely prevent lot of modifications. I can post a good solution including best software engineering practices but I thought of making the thought process easy and let it up to the user to use proper patterns and make a perfect solution out of it :). hope you agree on this. We do not believe in spoon feeding I have always been told on stackoverflow :)